# Detecting Dropped Connection Before Sending Response in MVC3 and C#

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have an MVC3 application which processes incoming requests, updates a database and, when required, sends a response which contains further commands to the requester.

There are timing constraints on how long the MVC application can take before sending a response so the application does the following:

1. Takes request content and stores it in an intermediate database for processing later in a separate service.
2. Checks the database for outgoing response objects (just lines of plain text) and if any exist adds them to the response and marks them as sent in the database.
3. Sends the response with and outgoing response objects in the body.

This all works nicely except for the fact that the objects are marked as sent even if the response never gets to the requester e.g. if it drops its connection during the server's processing.

So, essentially, is there any way, say, by using action filters, that I can check the status of the requester's connection before committing the changes to the database and sending back the response?

Answer (score 0):

could you do something like a try and catch?

```
try
{
   //Sends the response with and outgoing response objects in the body.
   //mark it as sent
}
catch
{
   //dont do anything as the "object" wont have been set a "sent" its gonna try the next time?
}
```

Also you could check the state of the connection before sending/marking as sent

Comment: I'm just calling 'return View(responseObjects);' in the controller. Even if the connection is dropped, it seems to function perfectly.

Comment: it doesnt pop an exception?

Comment: can you try to do while(Connection.State is alive) ? i dont remember the syntax fully for the state..

Comment: Nope. Nothing. The Application_Error handler isn't called either.

Comment: i cant think of any reason why it would fail but not create an exception at least in debug mode. Could you debug line by line for the View method and see if something appears in there?

Comment: Where would I find the Connection.State property? There is property called IsClientConnected in the controller's Response object but this is true even if the connection is dropped.

Comment: what DB connection are you using? MySQL,MicrosoftSQL,OLEBD?

Comment: I'm not interested in the DB connection. I can detect errors at the DB no problem. It's the TCP/HTTP connection that I'm interested in.

Comment: for the TCP connection in order to know if its alive you must sent a "heartbeat". Every X miliseconds you send something to the server and wait for a response if there is none then you consider the connection dead.

Comment: this might be usefull [link](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/TCP-Keepalive-HOWTO/overview.html)

Comment: I would expect IIS to keep a check on the TCP connection and, somehow, report it to the MVC3 framework -- at least that's how I would want it to work ;). I don't want to be digging into the TCP/IP stack when all I want is an 'IsClientStillConnected' type property to query.

Comment: you lost me there... 
are you doing something like 

'SQLCon = new SqlConnection("server=Aserver;TrustedConnection=no;database=YOURDB;");`

?

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding the question. I want to check the status of the client's connection before sending a response (or at least committing my changes to the database). That's all; the database connection is fine. This question is not about the connection to the database, it's about the connection to the client.

Comment: well then the only way i know of is the one i said before with the hearbeat which will check the state of the connection by getting a response or not.